# Unable to save to a text file using Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to save some text to a text file in vbscript but it doesnt work, nor does it show any errors. Here's the code:

```
sub SaveToFile()
    dim fso, fl
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fl = fso.OpenTextFile "C:\myFile.txt", 2, True
    fl.Write("blahblah")
    fl.Close : Set fl = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    end sub
```

I was having hard time to post the html code, so here is the link to the code:[here](http://sharetext.org/R3Lx)

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes you want to append some content to an existing textfile. According [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) you have to tell the runtime enviroment that you want append something. If so, you have to use the constant value `8` instead of `2`.

Comment: I tried the example on the link that you posted, still no luck. Btw, all I am trying to do is make a file if it doesnt exist already and write some text on to it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you posted the entire code in your script: you define a procedure there, but you don't call it anywhere. Add a line `SaveToFile` to your script to actually call the procedure. Also, the parameter list for `OpenTextFile` must be in parentheses when the returned object is assigned to a variable. The written text OTOH should not be between parantheses (although it doesn't hurt in this particular situation).

```
Sub SaveToFile()
    Dim fso, fl
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fl = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\myFile.txt", 2, True)
    fl.Write "blahblah"
    fl.Close
    Set fl = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
end sub

SaveToFile
```

Comment: I am calling this sub through a button like this:    <TD height="40"><INPUT id=saveToFile style="WIDTH: 135px; HEIGHT: 24px" onclick=SaveToFile() type=button size=46 value="Save To File" name=cmdSaveToFile></TD>

Comment: Preventing missunderstandings: Do you want to write a .wsh-Script -executed on local computer- or a script that will be execute on server side, using a webbrowser?

Comment: @Ridey Please provide more context. Is this an ASP page? An HTA? A WSH script? Something else entirely?

Comment: What I am trying to do is, I have an html page where I have a save button that is supposed to save some text to a text file on my file system. In the vbscript, I am using an activex control that captures signature from a signature pad that is connected to my machine. The code that I posted above was just to test if the file is being saved or not. But my ultimate goal would be to save the signature in a Base64String format to a text file. But I am unable to save a simple text file to begin with.

Comment: Your browser security settings are probably preventing filesystem access. After all, you don't want random web pages to be able to write to your local harddisk at their own discretion. What zone is your page in?

Comment: @Ansgar I am not sure what you meant by zone. And FYI I am using IE9 with default security and privacy settings.

Comment: @Ansgar all the zones are set to medium by default, except for restricted sites, which is set to high.

Comment: And? Did you try lowering the security level for the zone your page is in?

Comment: @Ansgar I tried. But after some testing, I think the problem is with the SaveToFile() sub, it is not getting called. Even if I put a simple line of code to display a msg box, it is not doing anything.

Comment: Worked just fine when I tested it with a local HTML file in IE9. Please update your question with your whole HTML file.

Comment: Tested the code from your update, and it worked as well when I saved it to a local file and opened it in IE. Thus it's most definitely a problem with the browser security settings.